# How would I remove the scroll bounce on the overall window while maintaining scroll capability?

Tags: html, css

I tried the "hidden" overflow property but that completely removes the scrolling capability; as well as, fixing the first_block in place. When the overflow property is on "scroll" all of the divs are visible.

```
html{
overflow: hidden;
}

body{
height: 100%;
width: 100%
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
}

div#container{
height: 100%;
}

div#static_nav{
text-align: right;
}

div#block_one{
height: 100vh;
}

div#block_two{
height: 100vh:
}
```

Here is the HTML

Here, the first_block div content is displayed but each individual div should be 100vh(from the css). I'm not quite sure how to remedy this.

```
<head>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "tof_css.css" />
<script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
family=Kanit|Heebo|Source+Sans+Pro">
</head>

<body>
<div id = "container">

<header>
  <div id = "static_nav">
    <nav class = "navbar">
      <a href = "block_one">HOME</a>
      <a href = "block_two">ABOUT</a>
      <a href = "block_four">PEOPLE</a>
      <a href = "block_five">CONTACT</a>
      <a href = "">LOG IN</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<div id = "block_one">
test 1
</div>

<div id = "block_two">
test 2
</div>

<div id = "block_three">
test 3
</div>

<div id = "block_four">
test 4
</div>

<div id = "block_five">
test
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake on the last line in the CSS, you have colon `:` intead of a semicolon `;`

BTW, keep it simple
JSfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/pg0tpg05](https://jsfiddle.net/pg0tpg05/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0; /* remove default margin */
}

div#static_nav {
  text-align: right;
}

#container > div {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <header>
    <div id="static_nav">
      <nav class="navbar">
        <a href="block_one">HOME</a>
        <a href="block_two">ABOUT</a>
        <a href="block_four">PEOPLE</a>
        <a href="block_five">CONTACT</a>
        <a href="">LOG IN</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div id="block_one">
    test 1
  </div>

  <div id="block_two">
    test 2
  </div>

  <div id="block_three">
    test 3
  </div>

  <div id="block_four">
    test 4
  </div>

  <div id="block_five">
    test
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. It's definitely more efficient. I'm still getting a bounce when I run the code in browser.

Comment: I don't see any bounce... Perhaps there is some other code messing things up? Or maybe it's just the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the issue I was having was due to height of the body being set to 100%; meaning the body could NOT exceed the parameters of the browser window, so there would be no overflow. Setting the body height to 100vh makes the height relative to the browser not equal to it thus allowing for overflow conditions.